# Error en SQL - Solo una expresión puede ser especificada

Tags: sql, substring

Estoy tratando de separar una cadena "1532" en `SQL` pero obtengo este error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

¿Quizás es porque estoy haciéndolo en una tabla temporal?

Este es el código:

`@hh varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) Hora, substring(Hora, 1, 2) as hhx from# stats_ddl)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es tal cual lo que dice el error:

```
SELECT @hh = (SELECT TOP(1) Hora, substring(Hora, 1, 2) as hhx 
                     from stats_ddl)
```

Estas retornando dos columnas que quieres guardar en una sola variable, eso es inválido, lo que si puedes es hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT TOP 1
       @Variable1 =  Hora, 
       @Variable2 =  substring(Hora, 1, 2)
                     from stats_ddl
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

El problema es *como dicen los demás*, tienes dos columnas en una sola:

*Ejemplo:*

```
@hh varchar(50) = (SELECT TOP(1)  substring(Hora, 1, 2) as hhx from# stats_ddl)
```

De esta forma tu consulta tiene solo una columna y ésta será almacenada en la variable.

Comment: saludos y gracias por ayudar, pero en SO se espera no solo código en las respuestas si no una explicación además, comenta ¿por qué ese código soluciona el problema?

Comment: Bienvenido Christian. Como bien te comenta @AlfredoPaz, en [es.so] tratamos de buscar respuestas de alta calidad. Te recomiendo que leas [answer] para tener una guía de como actuar. Un saludo y gracias por tu respuesta :)